# How to get users from multiple membership providerspicker in people picker

Tags: authentication, forms-authentication, people-picker

I've implemented a custom membership provider that authenticate users from a custom sharepoint list .

I've added membership provider and role provider to :

- my web app web.config
- central administration web.config
- STS web.config

and every thing worked fine.

**Problem:**

people pickers in my web application retrieves only FBA users from custom membership provider (by calling `FindUsersByEmail` and `FindUsersByName`) but they don't show active directory users (domain users) although I didn't remove default membership provider from my web.config .

your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The SharePoint People Picker will only show users from the user sources that are enabled for the current web application's zone. So if you enabled FBA but removed unchecked Windows Authentication (for instance to only allow FBA users to sign on this zone), then they won't be able to pick AD users.

If you want to see both FBA and AD users, you must enable both Windows and FBA authentication types in the Authentication Providers page for that web app (Central Administration ==> Manage web applications ==> select web app ==> press Authentication Providers button in SharePoint ribbon). There's really no way around this.

Comment: both windows authentication and FBA are already enabled

Comment: If that's the case, then try typing Get-SPClaimProvider from a SharePoint PowerShell command and verify that the Active Directory Claim Provider is visible. If not, you'll have to make it visible. But in all likelihood, your issue is elsewhere. It's difficult to know without having access to your environment though but the SharePoint ULS log and the server envent log should be your starting points to troubleshoot it.

Comment: it's already there and enabled , but 
IsUsedByDefault  is set to False , do you know how to set it to true ?